# Building new dual boot PC: Does Ubuntu get installed first or second?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm going to build a new PC in the next few days that I want to be dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 Home.

Which OS should I install first, and are there any special details for installing both OS on a new build?

I've only added Linux & Ubuntu to machines with an existing OS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would install Windows first, because it makes partitioning easier and Ubuntu gives you an option to install alongside Windows or windows boot manager. It is ALWAYS easier to install windows first then Ubuntu. It will always be more stable to install windows first then Ubuntu.